# See the source code of a shiny page Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

I have a small question. I am currently working on Rstudio and more precisely on shiny and I was wondering if there was a website or a web extension to be able to see the code of a shiny page? I have for example access to a shiny page and I would like to see the code to simply train myself to reproduce it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Alternatively you could have a look here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/ There all the code is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Because shiny `ui.R` and `app.R` files are used to compile web apps via a shiny server which are then served across the internet I imagine (but don't know for certain) it would be impossible to access the  underlying `.R` files without being able to access the server itself to access those `.R` files manually.

But if you are looking for resources containing code for `shiny` you could try the following two resources that give basic and slightly more advanced introductions to `shiny`:

- [Shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)
- [Mastering Shiny online book](https://mastering-shiny.org) (written by Hadley Wickham)

If you are wanting to know how to do a particular thing on a `shiny` app from the website you are interested in maybe you can ask that in a new question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't think it would be possible but it would have been nice...

Comment: No problem - @Julian's suggestion might be helpful too. That is probably the closest you'll get i think.

Comment: Yeah there is maybe an another way with a extension or something like that but I dont know…